# How can I use Grid.ColumnDefinition as something like a style template?

Tags: c#, xaml, grid

Is it possible to use Grid.ColumnDefinition as a style template?
My present code is the following.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="Column1" Width="40"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="Column2" Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="Column3" Width="80"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- Some elements here-->
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column1, Path=Width}"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column2, Path=Width}"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column3, Path=Width}"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- Some elements here-->
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

I'd like to remove ElementNames from this, i.e. I'd like to use ColumnDefinition alone of a Grid as something like a style template. Note that RowDedenitions vary from Grid to Grid.

Comment: I've given this a try. I've tried creating a ControlTemplate for your Grid, also tried setting Grid.ColumnDefinitions in a style for a grid. However I have had no luck. I don't think this is possible, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @MikeEason Thank you for your kindness. I found a solution in the following website. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/427355/WPF-Stylizing-RowDefinitions-and-ColumnDefinitions#divTab4C#